# AWS SES: How to handle bounces for Transactional emails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When it comes to marketing emails, when you receive a bounce or a complaint, you should simply remove the email address from the mailing list if it is a hard bounce or spam complaint.

However, how does AWS expect you to handle bounces or complaints from transactional emails (like a forgot password email), since there is no mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

For Bounce, you can use third-party APIs like zero bounce, etc. before sending the emails.
For complaints, if you are getting who are marking the mails as spam then stop sending them the emails. If not then there are many different ways of finding it through Amazon services itself.